# Apache not recognising password protected directory

Tags: apache-2.2, htpasswd

I want to password the directory `/rutorrent` on my website. In that directory, I've created this `.htaccess` file:

```
AuthUserFile /home/whitey/sites/localhost/.htpasswd
AuthName "Login to use rutorrent"
AuthType Basic

require valid-user
```

And then I have a `.htpasswd` file in `/home/whitey/sites/localhost/`:

```
whitey:f9kK77E4scRcI
```

I've generated the password using an online `.htpasswd` generator. I've restarted Apache, but when I go to the `/rutorrent` directory, I'm not prompted for a password.

Nothing shows up in the error logs, either.

Answer (score 2):

In order for Apache to use your `.htaccess` file, the base configuration must specify that you're allowed to override the configuration using the [`AllowOverride`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride) directive.  Further, the appropriate type of override must be allowed.  For Auth* and Require directives, you must have at the minimum (you can have other options in the list too, or `All`):

```
AllowOverride AuthConfig
```

set for the `<Directory>` the `.htaccess` file is in (or a directory above it, with no other directory disabling the directive)